After installation of pyogrio Could not detect PROJ data files. Set PROJ_LIB environment variable to the correct path. when importing gpkg
When I import a geopackage with only geopandas all is fine, however, if I try to use pyogrio like this in my jupyter notebook:
gpd.options.io_engine = "pyogrio"
network = gpd.read_file(r"path\to\file.gpkg")

I get the error:
RuntimeWarning: Could not detect PROJ data files.  Set PROJ_LIB environment variable to the correct path.
  _init_proj_data()


A little of context: I just created a fresh conda environment with Python=3.12 on Windows 10. I first installed ipykernel with conda, then I installed geopandas, then pyogrio, then pyarrow. All with conda-forge.
My packages installed in the environmet are in the list below.
The motivation to create a new environmet was as my old environment (Python version 10) which also had geopandas, pyogrio and pyarrow installed started to load files very slowly, so that I had the impression that pyogrio wasn't actually used anymore, but fell back to the default 'fiona' again.
So it seems to be a general problem, not just with the python version I guess.
What could cause the problem and how can I fix it? Has it something to do with jupyter notebook?

asttokens                 2.0.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
attrs                     23.2.0             pyh71513ae_0    conda-forge
aws-c-auth                0.7.22               ha390a07_2    conda-forge
aws-c-cal                 0.6.14               h750c3ff_1    conda-forge
aws-c-common              0.9.19               h2466b09_0    conda-forge
aws-c-compression         0.2.18               h750c3ff_6    conda-forge
aws-c-event-stream        0.4.2               he05106e_12    conda-forge
aws-c-http                0.8.1               h55c4ea9_17    conda-forge
aws-c-io                  0.14.8               ha255af7_5    conda-forge
aws-c-mqtt                0.10.4               heb8cf2b_4    conda-forge
aws-c-s3                  0.5.9                haf5e0f7_3    conda-forge
aws-c-sdkutils            0.1.16               h750c3ff_2    conda-forge
aws-checksums             0.1.18               h750c3ff_6    conda-forge
aws-crt-cpp               0.26.8              hb2f7e64_15    conda-forge
aws-sdk-cpp               1.11.329             hc79b3d8_2    conda-forge
azure-core-cpp            1.11.1               h249a519_1    conda-forge
azure-identity-cpp        1.6.0                h91493d7_1    conda-forge
azure-storage-blobs-cpp   12.10.0              h91493d7_1    conda-forge
azure-storage-common-cpp  12.5.0               h91493d7_4    conda-forge
blas                      1.0                         mkl    conda-forge
blosc                     1.21.5               hbd69f2e_1    conda-forge
boost-cpp                 1.74.0               h5b4e17d_6    conda-forge
bottleneck                1.3.7           py312he558020_0
branca                    0.7.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
brotli                    1.1.0                hcfcfb64_1    conda-forge
brotli-bin                1.1.0                hcfcfb64_1    conda-forge
brotli-python             1.0.9           py312hd77b12b_8
bzip2                     1.0.8                h2bbff1b_6
c-ares                    1.28.1               hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2024.6.2             h56e8100_0    conda-forge
cairo                     1.18.0               h1fef639_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2024.6.2           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cfitsio                   4.4.0                h9b0cee5_1    conda-forge
charset-normalizer        3.3.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
click                     8.1.7           win_pyh7428d3b_0    conda-forge
click-plugins             1.1.1                      py_0    conda-forge
cligj                     0.7.2              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
colorama                  0.4.6           py312haa95532_0
comm                      0.2.1           py312haa95532_0
contourpy                 1.2.0           py312h59b6b97_0
cycler                    0.12.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
debugpy                   1.6.7           py312hd77b12b_0
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
executing                 0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
expat                     2.6.2                hd77b12b_0
fiona                     1.9.6           py312h4a86439_3    conda-forge
fmt                       10.2.1               h181d51b_0    conda-forge
folium                    0.16.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-dejavu-sans-mono 2.37                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-inconsolata      3.000                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-source-code-pro  2.038                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-ubuntu           0.83                 h77eed37_2    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.14.2               hbde0cde_0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-ecosystem     1                             0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-forge         1                             0    conda-forge
fonttools                 4.51.0          py312h2bbff1b_0
freetype                  2.12.1               hdaf720e_2    conda-forge
freexl                    2.0.0                h8276f4a_0    conda-forge
gdal                      3.9.0           py312h7090a6d_4    conda-forge
geopandas                 0.14.4             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
geopandas-base            0.14.4             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
geos                      3.12.1               h1537add_0    conda-forge
geotiff                   1.7.3                hfbd0779_0    conda-forge
gettext                   0.22.5               h5728263_2    conda-forge
gettext-tools             0.22.5               h7d00a51_2    conda-forge
hdf4                      4.2.15               h5557f11_7    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.14.3          nompi_h73e8ff5_101    conda-forge
icc_rt                    2022.1.0             h6049295_2
icu                       73.2                 h63175ca_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.7                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2023.2.0         h57928b3_50497    conda-forge
ipykernel                 6.28.0          py312haa95532_0
ipython                   8.20.0          py312haa95532_0
jedi                      0.18.1          py312haa95532_1
jinja2                    3.1.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
joblib                    1.4.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_client            8.6.0           py312haa95532_0
jupyter_core              5.5.0           py312haa95532_0
kealib                    1.5.3                h6c43f9b_1    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.4.4           py312hd77b12b_0
krb5                      1.21.2               heb0366b_0    conda-forge
lcms2                     2.16                 h67d730c_0    conda-forge
lerc                      4.0.0                h63175ca_0    conda-forge
libabseil                 20240116.2      cxx17_h63175ca_0    conda-forge
libaec                    1.1.3                h63175ca_0    conda-forge
libarchive                3.7.4                haf234dc_0    conda-forge
libarrow                  16.1.0           hcb49941_5_cpu    conda-forge
libarrow-acero            16.1.0           he0c23c2_5_cpu    conda-forge
libarrow-dataset          16.1.0           he0c23c2_5_cpu    conda-forge
libarrow-substrait        16.1.0           h1f0e801_5_cpu    conda-forge
libasprintf               0.22.5               h5728263_2    conda-forge
libasprintf-devel         0.22.5               h5728263_2    conda-forge
libbrotlicommon           1.1.0                hcfcfb64_1    conda-forge
libbrotlidec              1.1.0                hcfcfb64_1    conda-forge
libbrotlienc              1.1.0                hcfcfb64_1    conda-forge
libcrc32c                 1.1.2                h0e60522_0    conda-forge
libcurl                   8.8.0                hd5e4a3a_0    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.20                 hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
libevent                  2.1.12               h3671451_1    conda-forge
libexpat                  2.6.2                h63175ca_0    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.4                hd77b12b_1
libgdal                   3.9.0                h4f813f3_4    conda-forge
libgettextpo              0.22.5               h5728263_2    conda-forge
libgettextpo-devel        0.22.5               h5728263_2    conda-forge
libglib                   2.80.2               h0df6a38_0    conda-forge
libgoogle-cloud           2.24.0               h5e7cea3_0    conda-forge
libgoogle-cloud-storage   2.24.0               hce61461_0    conda-forge
libgrpc                   1.62.2               h5273850_0    conda-forge
libhwloc                  2.9.1                h51c2c0f_0    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.17                 hcfcfb64_2    conda-forge
libintl                   0.22.5               h5728263_2    conda-forge
libintl-devel             0.22.5               h5728263_2    conda-forge
libjpeg-turbo             3.0.0                hcfcfb64_1    conda-forge
libkml                    1.3.0             hd45a9bc_1016    conda-forge
libnetcdf                 4.9.2           nompi_h07c049d_113    conda-forge
libparquet                16.1.0           h178134c_5_cpu    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.43               h19919ed_0    conda-forge
libpq                     16.3                 hab9416b_0    conda-forge
libprotobuf               4.25.3               h503648d_0    conda-forge
libre2-11                 2023.09.01           hf8d8778_2    conda-forge
librttopo                 1.1.0               h94c4f80_15    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h62dcd97_0
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h5a68840_5    conda-forge
libspatialite             5.1.0                h1b08085_6    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.46.0               h2466b09_0    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.11.0               h7dfc565_0    conda-forge
libthrift                 0.19.0               ha2b3283_1    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.6.0                hddb2be6_3    conda-forge
libutf8proc               2.8.0                h82a8f57_0    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.4.0                hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.15                 hcd874cb_0    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.12.7               h283a6d9_1    conda-forge
libzip                    1.10.1               h1d365fa_3    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.3.1                h2466b09_1    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.4                hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
lzo                       2.10              hcfcfb64_1001    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7    conda-forge
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2    conda-forge
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2    conda-forge
mapclassify               2.6.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
markupsafe                2.1.3           py312h2bbff1b_0
matplotlib-base           3.8.4           py312hc7c4135_0
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6           py312haa95532_0
minizip                   4.0.6                hb638d1e_0    conda-forge
mkl                       2023.2.0         h6a75c08_50497    conda-forge
mkl-service               2.4.0           py312h2bbff1b_1
mkl_fft                   1.3.8           py312h2bbff1b_0
mkl_random                1.2.4           py312h59b6b97_0
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1    conda-forge
nest-asyncio              1.6.0           py312haa95532_0
networkx                  3.3                pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
numexpr                   2.8.7           py312h96b7d27_0
numpy                     1.26.4          py312hfd52020_0
numpy-base                1.26.4          py312h4dde369_0
openjpeg                  2.5.2                h3d672ee_0    conda-forge
openssl                   3.3.1                h2466b09_0    conda-forge
orc                       2.0.1                h7e885a9_1    conda-forge
packaging                 23.2            py312haa95532_0
pandas                    2.2.1           py312h0158946_0
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pcre                      8.45                 h0e60522_0    conda-forge
pcre2                     10.43                h17e33f8_0    conda-forge
pillow                    10.3.0          py312h6f6a607_0    conda-forge
pip                       24.0            py312haa95532_0
pixman                    0.43.4               h63175ca_0    conda-forge
platformdirs              3.10.0          py312haa95532_0
poppler                   24.04.0              h747fd5a_0    conda-forge
poppler-data              0.4.12               hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
postgresql                16.3                 h7f155c9_0    conda-forge
proj                      9.4.0                he13c7e8_1    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.43          py312haa95532_0
prompt_toolkit            3.0.43               hd3eb1b0_0
psutil                    5.9.0           py312h2bbff1b_0
pthread-stubs             0.4               hcd874cb_1001    conda-forge
pthreads-win32            2.9.1                hfa6e2cd_3    conda-forge
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyarrow                   16.1.0          py312h7e22eef_3    conda-forge
pyarrow-core              16.1.0          py312h3529c54_3_cpu    conda-forge
pybind11-abi              5                    hd3eb1b0_0
pygments                  2.15.1          py312haa95532_1
pyogrio                   0.8.0           py312hd215820_2    conda-forge
pyparsing                 3.0.9              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyproj                    3.6.1           py312h6f27134_7    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1              pyh0701188_6    conda-forge
python                    3.12.3          h2628c8c_0_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.9.0post0      py312haa95532_2
python-tzdata             2024.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.12                    4_cp312    conda-forge
pytz                      2024.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pywin32                   305             py312h2bbff1b_0
pyzmq                     25.1.2          py312hd77b12b_0
qhull                     2020.2               h70d2c02_2    conda-forge
re2                       2023.09.01           hd3b24a8_2    conda-forge
requests                  2.32.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
rtree                     1.0.1           py312h2eaa2aa_0
scikit-learn              1.4.2           py312hc7c4135_1
scipy                     1.13.1          py312hbb039d4_0
setuptools                69.5.1          py312haa95532_0
shapely                   2.0.4           py312h91267bd_1    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
snappy                    1.2.0                hfb803bf_1    conda-forge
spdlog                    1.13.0               h64d2f7d_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.45.3               h2bbff1b_0
stack_data                0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
tbb                       2021.9.0             h91493d7_0    conda-forge
threadpoolctl             3.5.0              pyhc1e730c_0    conda-forge
tiledb                    2.23.0               h13740f5_1    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.13               h5226925_1    conda-forge
tornado                   6.3.3           py312h2bbff1b_0
traitlets                 5.14.3          py312haa95532_0
tzdata                    2024a                h04d1e81_0
ucrt                      10.0.22621.0         h57928b3_0    conda-forge
unicodedata2              15.1.0          py312h2bbff1b_0
uriparser                 0.9.8                h5a68840_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   2.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
vc                        14.3                h8a93ad2_20    conda-forge
vc14_runtime              14.40.33810         ha82c5b3_20    conda-forge
vs2015_runtime            14.40.33810         h3bf8584_20    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
wheel                     0.43.0          py312haa95532_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_6    conda-forge
xerces-c                  3.2.5                h63175ca_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxau               1.0.11               hcd874cb_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                hcd874cb_0    conda-forge
xyzservices               2024.6.0           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.4.6                h8cc25b3_1
zeromq                    4.3.5                hd77b12b_0
zlib                      1.3.1                h2466b09_1    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.6                h0ea2cb4_0    conda-forge


A RuntimeWarning isn't an error, it's a warning. That said, I can't reproduce. Usually that warning is seen when the conda environment isn't activated properly. How are you activating the conda environment and starting notebook?

I'm using conda environments with jupyter notebook since a couple of years now, so I don't think the error is caused by it. However, I think I then gave the wrong the error message, as I actually get one after the JN cell and one really at the end, which is CRSError: Invalid projection: EPSG:25833: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: no database context specified).

What I read so far this is a pyproj error, however, I'm unsure how to handle it as it seems to affect both environments, the old one, which was always working fine, and the new one.

I just validated it with my older environment. It is all a bit quirky, as when I use pyogrio in my older environment it works, when I use it like it: test = gpd.read_file(r"pyth\to\file.gpkg", engine='pyogrio'). However, in my new environment I get the error as given above.

Did you use the recommendation given here? I think the packages where conda-forge is not mentioned are coming from defaults or am I mistaken? It is also safer to install everything you want installed in one call to conda, so all dependencies can be resolved in one time instead of adding packages one by one.

Hi @Pieter I think you are right, that some packages are installed from conda-forge and some just by default. I have read often, that it is advised to install all package from the same source, however, I wonder what if I need to install some package which can only be installed with another packagemanager, e.g. with pip? Doesn't that lead to some problems? After all I use conda as environment as it gives the freedom to use more that one package manager (e.g. sometimes I use conda-forge, conda or pip, depending on the installation advise from that specific package).

But I will try it the recommended way, by installing all packages via conda-forge. I just wonder how it is then with other packages which I would also need in that environment but is advised to be installed with another packagemanager.

@i.i.k. the main source of problems of mixing installs from conda vs conda-forge is that compiled code (e.g. in C, C++) is built in different ways and/or using different versions, leading to binary incompatibilities. So for pip, the same logic applies.

Because pure python isn't compiled code, for many pip packages there won't be any problem. Only when a pip package also includes wheels from binaries, you can have the same problems as when mixing conda. If you run into a problem, most of the time the binary dependency will also be available on conda-forge, so you can just install that package first from conda-forge, and then install the pip package... This way the conda-forge package will be used instead of the wheel.

@Pieter Thank you very much for the thorough explanation!
